# Find Marginal CDF given joint CDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image: The question relates to joint CDF and Marginal CDF]

[image]

This is my approach so far, but I am unsure what to do with part 2. I found the joint PDF and Marginal CDF's but don't fully grasp the question.